# How to do OR in activerecord query with deep associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have locations that have an associated city and state, where each city and state have a report associated with it. The report has an attribute 'good_weather'.

How can I query the locations where either the associated city OR state have good_weather = true?

Here's what I have so far but it's not working:

```
Location.includes(city: [:report], state: [:report])
.where("cities.reports.good_weather = true OR states.reports.good_weather = true")
.references(:cities, :states, :reports)
```

Models look like this:

```
Location has_one :city, has_one :state
City belongs_to :location, belongs_to :report
State belongs_to :location, belongs_to :report
Report has_one :city, has_one :state
```

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "reports"
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "reports", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: How do your models look like?

Comment: I added models to post

Comment: No, that doesn't work b/c you're skipping the whole report association. "column states.good_weather does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
Location.joins(:city, :state)
        .joins("INNER JOIN reports 
                ON reports.good_weather = true AND 
                   (reports.id = cities.report_id OR 
                    reports.id = states.report_id)")
        .distinct
```